# solr Japanese tokenizer not working for katakana

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tokenize, solr-schema

I am using solr-6.2.0 and filedType : text_ja .
I am facing problem with JapaneseTokenizer, its properly tokenising 
 ドラゴンボールヒーロー  
 ↓ 
"ドラゴン"     
"ドラゴンボールヒーロー"     
"ボール" "ヒーロー"

But its failing to tokenize ドラゴンボールヒーローズ properly,
ドラゴンボールヒーローズ

 ↓ 
"ドラゴン"      
"ドラゴンボールヒーローズ"     
"ボールヒーローズ"

Hence searching with ドラゴンボール doesn't hit in later case .

Also it doesn't seperate ディズニーランド into two words .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using **lucene-gosen Sen Tokenizer**,
 and compiling ipadic dictionary with custom rules and word weights.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm fairly certain that it is working as intended. Looking into how the [Kuromoji morphpological analyzer](http://www.atilika.org/) works would probably be the best way to gain a better understanding of it's rules and rationale.

There are a couple of things you could try. You could put the JapaneseAnalyzer into `EXTENDED`, instead of `SEARCH` mode, which should give you significant looser matching (though most likely at the cost of introducing more false positives, of course):

```
Analyzer analyzer = new JapaneseAnalyzer(
        null, 
        JapaneseTokenizer.Mode.EXTENDED, 
        JapaneseAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet(), 
        JapaneseAnalyzer.getDefaultStopTags()
        );
```

Or you could try using [CJKAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKAnalyzer.html), instead.

(By the way, EnglishAnalyzer doesn't split "Disneyland" into two tokens either)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, CJKAnalyzer will creates lot of tokens which doesn't have any meaning, also EXTENDED mode unigrams english words, I considered using JapaneseTokenzer itself with custom userDictionary, is there any readily available dictionary ?, any idea ?